# Right design to structurally ensure data consistency

Tags: mysql, doctrine

In my current design, I have **app_group**, **student** and **group_article**:

[image]

To structurally ensure that a **group_article** is only associated with a **student** from that same group, the foreign keys "publisher" and "app_group" are taken from the join entity **group_member** (1) as opposed to having them issued from **student** and **app_group** individually. This way, someone with the right to insert new records into the database cannot introduce incoherent data such as adding an article that have been written by a student that isn't even in that group which would be poor design. Now, I want generalize this approach into multiple students or multiple groups. I now have **group_message**, **group_message_in** and **group_message_out** which is an inheritance chain (**group_message** is the base which is an abstract entity in Symfony, and both **group_message_in** and group_message_out extend it):

[image]

Initially, I was planning to embed the group foreign key on the base class (**group_message**) and have the sender/recipient (respectively on **group_message_out** and **group_message_in**) be taken from student directly:

[image]

However, this  will leave the database vulnerable to incoherence as per the first example, eg: student from group A can be associated with a message that targets student from group B which is not desirable (only students from the same group can exchange **group_message**).

I'm well aware that I can amend this risk in code but I want a similar solution to (1) and to know if this is achievable with Doctrine since MySQL itself might have ways of solving a similar problem that aren't supported by Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

A relational solution to your problem would look something like this:
[image: relational model of your problem]

The integrity that you seek would be achieved by the PK-FK relationships and by assigning a student to a group using the groupName colums.

Your question then becomes something like "How can I use Doctrine to do the same thing?"

To the best of my knowledge Doctrine uses a set of PHP libraries to create what its proponents call a "persistence layer" that stores what it calls "Entities". With Doctrine, the term "Entity" is a synonym for "Class" in the OO paradigm.
In other words Doctrine stores classes in the data layer.

And now we can see the problem.
A relational schema is a structure of relations which is a completely different kind of artefact than a collection of classes.

The OO/Relational divide has been called an "[impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)". Unfortunately this term obscures more than it reveals.

To quote from the Wikipedia article: "There have been some attempts at building object-oriented database management systems (OODBMS) that would avoid the impedance mismatch problem. They have been less successful in practice than relational databases however, partly due to the limitations of OO principles as a basis for a data model."

I suggest that you also review Ted Neward's article  "[The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/)."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the solution but I did notice that student, in your example, has the property groupName which suggests that it's in a Many-To-One relationship with group which would imply that a student can only be in one group at a time which is not the case for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is exactly how ORM is supposed to work. If the modeler (Me in this case) makes a mistake, then the domain expert(You) can point out the mistake and the modeler updates the model. I can't show the new solution in this comment box so I will create a new answer so that you can compare the differences. 
I created the new solution by changing just one constraint in the object-role model.

Answer (score 0):

This new answer shows the object-role model, the relational schema that it generates and the logic that is implied by the new constraint (shown by the red arrow)

The object- role model.
[image]

This is the logic that is asserted by the fact type Student(.id) is a member of Group(.name)
[image]

Now as the domain expert, you can read this verbalization and tell me whether it is True or False in your domain.
Please note that all I did as the modeler, was to change the constraint (shown by the red arrow) and the ORM tool called NORMA generated the new verbalization that you see here.

When the domain expert agrees that the model conforms to the requirements then it takes a few seconds to generate the SQL DDL that can then be used to create a new database schema in an RDBMS.